# One to many relationship with objects using EF core

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, relational-database

I have four entities:

Employee: It belongs to Group and Department entities
Group: Contains a list of Employees
Department: Contains a list of Employees
Todo: Assigned to a Group

The thing is: I tried to add FK to the tables and like 10 other approaches but I just can't figure it out. Let's see for example Department:

```
public class Department
    {
        public Department()
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Field { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the Employee entity:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot exceed 50 characters")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_0+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Format")]
        [Display(Name = "Office Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public Department Department { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Group")]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }
```

I generated a simple controller and view page for Departments
and in the details method I try to print out the `department.Employees.Count()` but it says it's 0.

Here is my appDbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasData(
                new Employee() { EmployeeId = -99, Name = "Mary", Email = "mary@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { EmployeeId = -98, Name = "Stan", Email = "stan@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { EmployeeId = -97, Name = "Mike", Email = "mike@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasData(
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -99, Field = "IT", Name = "Programming Department" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -98, Field = "HR", Name = "Human Resorcues" },
                new Department() { DepartmentId = -97, Field = "AD", Name = "Advertisement Department" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has a lot of "holes" and you must still trying and learning. So this question will be updated if you need more asistance.

I think you are having troubles to understand objects.

If you want to do it in your e.g., the departament has a list of employees (as I can see in your statement):

But:

```
   public List<Employee> Employees 
    {
      get; set;
    }
```

and then:

```
 new Department() { DepartmentId = -99, Field = "IT", Name = "Programming Department", Employees = x },
```

where x is an instance or List that keep or is this itself:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasData(
                new Employee() { EmployeeId = -99, Name = "Mary", Email = "mary@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { EmployeeId = -98, Name = "Stan", Email = "stan@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 },
                new Employee() { EmployeeId = -97, Name = "Mike", Email = "mike@gmail.com", DepartmentId = -99, GroupId = -1 })
```

But for database is more easy with E.F.:

```
//Save your employee in the context.
_context.Employees.Add(newemployee);
//Set the employee in the departament
thedepartament.Employees.Add(newemployee); 
//Save everything
_context.SaveChanges();
```

**UPDATE:**

Of course you won't create a departament everytime you "add" a new "employee", the above example is only for insert a relation child at the same time. So what you need is thinking in this way:

```
//Save your employee in the context.
_context.Employees.Add(newemployee);
//Search for the departament you want to add this employee, with a query:
Departament thedepOfTheNewEmployee = _context.Departament.Where(your conditions to search it).FirstOfDefault();
//Set the employee to that departament
newemployee.DepartmentId = thedepOfTheNewEmployee.Id;
//Save everything
_context.SaveChanges();
```

More further theory:
If you Add your element to the context, will be provided (virtually) an Id to retrieve. This theory is not for your scenario, but will help you in the future.

Comment: The main problem for me that it's not creating an Employees col in Departments table, only DepartmentId, Name, Field

Comment: @DobiTamás is logic. Are you working with LinQ and EF to retrieve the data from database?

Comment: Yes! And I have a col in the view which shows the .Count of the Employees List.

Comment: You helped a lot! Thank you very much! I was away from computer for a few days. Thank you!